# Visual Basic - How do you open subroutines using the console?

Tags: vba, visual-studio, console-application, subroutine

I've run into a few problems during one of my coding tasks.

I need the user to have a list of subroutines they can access while they're using the console. For example:

1: List of products.
2: Shopping basket.
3: Checkout.

Here is a car database program I found online (please click the link because I cannot post images yet):
[http://imgur.com/a/9sIm4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epc4v.png)

I need a similar list of options the user can access.

Your help with the completion of this task would be much appreciated.

Comment: Specify the problems you have run into and post your current code.

Comment: If you're using visual-studio, then you want VB.net, not VBA.

Comment: Use multiple `Console.Write()` and/or `Console.WriteLine()` calls to **DISPLAY** your menu to the user.  Then use a `String` variable and `Console.ReadLine()` to get a response from the user.  Finally, use some kind of conditional statement (like `If` or `Select Case`) to execute the desired subroutine.